# Are there any issues migrating from RHEL to CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat, weblogic

I want to migrate off of RHEL 6.3 to CentOS-6 to save in licensing costs. We will mainly be running Java/WebLogic 11g on these boxes. Are there any issues that I should be aware of when migrating from RHEL 6.3 to CentOS-6? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No issues at all. The conversion can even be done online/live.

If you have hardware drivers (e.g. HP ProLiant), you may need to modify your `/etc/redhat-release` to reflect RHEL instead of CentOS.

[CentOS has an official migration guide as well.](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that CentOS is downstream from RHEL and therefore you can experience a delay in receiving updated packages (errata).